# Why the first element missing when using the function span?

Tags: scala

The function below generates a `List`

```
def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x::xs =>
    val (first, rest) = xs span(y => y==x)
    first::pack(rest)
}
```

When applying `pack` on a list

```
val lis4 = List("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a")
```

I get a result

```
res3: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, a), List(), List(c), List())
```

However, according to the course given by Martin Odersky on coursera,

[image]

it should generate a result

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shadowing `xs` defined at the method level with the local binding of `xs` inside the pattern match. Notice in Oderskys example, the local pattern match bind is called `xs1`:

```
def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: xs1 =>
    val (first, rest) = xs span(y => y == x)
    first :: pack(rest)
}
```

To make this even clearer, you can ignore the tail part of the list in the pattern match using `_`:

```
def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: _ =>
    val (first, rest) = xs span(y => y == x)
    first :: pack(rest)
}
```

Yields:

```
scala> pack(List("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"))
res2: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, a, a), List(b), List(c, c), List(a))
```